# What's the easiest way to remove overall factors from polynomials?

Tags: function-construction, polynomials, expression-manipulation

I have code that outputs polynomials (in `#1`) such as the ones below (note that the trailing `Function` character `&` is left off for later):

```
poly1 = 1/64 (3 c^2 e - f^2 - #1) (c^2 (4 e + b^2 g) - 4 (f^2 + #1))^2 (c^2 (4 e + (a^2 + b^2) g) - 4 (f^2 + #1));

poly2 = -(1/64) (b^2 c^2 - 4 #1)^2 (a^2 c^2 + b^2 c^2 - 4 #1) #1;

poly3 = #1^42 (-(1/2) c^2 d^2 + #1)^6;
```

I'd like to process these polynomials to

1. drop overall prefactors (like 1/64 from `poly1` and `poly2`), and
2. and drop factors that are powers of `#1` alone

so that results should look like:

```
(*1*)  (3 c^2 e - f^2 - #1) (c^2 (4 e + b^2 g) - 4 (f^2 + #1))^2 (c^2 (4 e + (a^2 + b^2) g) - 4 (f^2 + #1))

(*2*)  (b^2 c^2 - 4 #1)^2 (a^2 c^2 + b^2 c^2 - 4 #1)

(*3*)  (-(1/2) c^2 d^2 + #1)^6
```

Is there a fail-proof way to get the job done?

Comment: `&` isn't a "trailing function character". Don't left it off "for later"

Comment: @Dr.belisarius I didn't mean to use "trailing function character" as a technical term.  I'm just saying that I'm not adding it for certain reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not entirely well defined due to handling of numbers, but the following should be at least close to what's wanted.

```
poly1 = 1/64 (3 c^2 e - f^2 - 
     x) (c^2 (4 e + b^2 g) - 
      4 (f^2 + x))^2 (c^2 (4 e + (a^2 + b^2) g) - 4 (f^2 + x));
poly2 = -(1/64) (b^2 c^2 - 4 x)^2 (a^2 c^2 + b^2 c^2 - 4 x) x;
poly3 = x^42 (-(1/2) c^2 d^2 + x)^6;

removeFactorsIn[poly_, keep_] := 
 With[{allbut2 = FactorTermsList[poly, keep][[3 ;; -1]]}, 
  Times @@ Factor[allbut2]]

keepVars = {b, c, e, f, g};

In[52]:= removeFactorsIn[poly1, keepVars]

(* Out[52]= (4 c^2 e - 4 f^2 + b^2 c^2 g - 4 x)^2 (4 c^2 e - 4 f^2 + 
   a^2 c^2 g + b^2 c^2 g - 4 x) (3 c^2 e - f^2 - x) *)

In[54]:= removeFactorsIn[poly2, keepVars]

(* Out[54]= (b^2 c^2 - 4 x)^2 (a^2 c^2 + b^2 c^2 - 4 x) *)

In[53]:= removeFactorsIn[poly3, keepVars]

(* Out[53]= (c^2 d^2 - 2 x)^6 *)
```

Comment: What is `keepVars` supposed to be?  Do I put `x` in there?  Comment: the most essential thing for my application is only to drop powers of `x`.  Dropping of constants is only for cosmetic reasons.  Since you say the second part is not "well defined", would it be easier to code it with this relaxed request?

Comment: @QuantumDot Sorry, I forgot to paste that in originally. It's there now. Not `x` but rather all other variables go in there (which I confess I find confusing, but that was the original design well before I happend onto the function).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Replace[poly, {_Rational -> 1, x^_. -> 1}, {1}]
```

This line assumes that the overall prefactors are rationals (but you could easily add `_Complex` if needed) and that the head of `poly` is indeed `Times`.